# How to represent a sequence minus an unspecified element?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, notation

How does one schematically represent a sequence that differs from another sequence only in that it is missing just one element, without specifying which element is missing?

Say I represent a sequence $S_1$ of $n$ elements where $n\ge 2$ as $(i_1, \dotsc, i_n)$. Now I want to represent another sequence $S_2$ which differs from $S_1$ only in that it is missing one element, represented as $i_j$. It is the $j$-th element in the sequence $S_1$, but I want to allow $j$ to have any value $1\le j \le n$. Is there a notation for schematically representing $(i_1,\dotsc,i_n)$ without $i_j$?

(Note: I am not a mathematician, so if I have misused any terms here, feel free to correct me.)

Comment: I've seen the circumflex notation used to indicate that a term was being deleted from a set, as in $(i_1, i_2, \cdots, \hat {i_j}, \cdots, i_n)=(i_1, i_2, \cdots, i_{j-1}, i_{j+1}, \cdots, i_n)$.  Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In his text [*Algebraic Topology*](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) (page 105), Hatcher uses a "hat" (or circumflex) to denote an $(n-1)$-tuple which is produced by removing the "hatted" element from an $n$-tuple.  For example,
$$ (i_1, \dotsc, \hat{i}_j, \dotsc, i_n)
= (i_1, \dotsc, i_{j-1}, i_{j+1}, \dotsc, i_n), $$
where $j$ is any index between $1$ and $n$, inclusive.  I would not say that this is universally standard notation, but Hatcher is a popular text on the topic, so folk are likely to have at least *seen* the notation at some point in their lives (assuming that they went to grad school in mathematics...?).  If you desire something more compact, perhaps define a function $\delta$ (the Greek letter delta, for "delete") on the space of finite tuples by
$$ \delta_j(i_1, \dotsc, i_n)
:= (i_1, \dotsc, \hat{i}_j, \dotsc, i_n) $$
would be appropriate (where the hat notation is as defined above)?  In the example given in the question, this notation gives
$ \delta_j(S_1) = S_2$.

Whatever notation you use, it will almost certainly be a little non-standard, so make sure that you give a clear definition before you start using it.

Answer (score 2):

If your original sequence is $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$, you can define the sequence that is missing $a_j$ as $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{j-1},a_{j+1},\ldots\}$. You could also call it $b^j$ and then you would have

$$b^j_n=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}a_n&\text{if }n<j\\a_{n+1}&\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right..$$